# Obtener la fecha de creación de un contacto

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Utilizando el nuevo [Contacts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328) en iOS 9, ¿cómo puedo obtener la fecha de creación del contacto?

En versiones anteriores, usando el Address Book Framework, podía hacer:

```
ABRecordRef person = ...
NSDate *creationDate = (__bridge_transfer NSDate *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonCreationDateProperty);
```

pero usando el nuevo framework no encontré ninguna propiedad en `CNContact` ni ninguna "key" para poder obtener este valor.

Comment: Aparentemente esto fue marcado como obsoleto en iOS 9.0, y no eres el único buscando su retorno. Aquí algunas referencias: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786677/getting-date-a-contact-was-added-to-the-address-book-in-swift-2-ios-9), también hay un request en [OpenRadar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5915838058070016) para esto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo, definitivamente acceder a esa propiedad con el `Contacts Framework` es imposible, ya que no existe. La única forma es utilizando el `ABF` o un wrapper de `ABF` como `APAddressBook`. Tal vez si generas un ticket a `Apple` puedas reportar el problema ya que no es el único.